# H2 Database sort string timestamp in yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS'Z'

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I have requirement to sort the String datetime in yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS'Z' format using the h2 query using java

```
TIME_ORDER
2021-03-08T01:00:01.000000800Z
2021-03-08T01:02:48.000000735Z
2021-03-08T12:58:02.000000016Z
2021-03-08T01:03:48.000000735Z
2021-03-08T01:04:48.000000735Z
```

how to sort this format in H2 , i tried with

```
SELECT TIME_ORDER FROM TABLE1 order by PARSEDATETIME(TIME_ORDER,'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ')
```

i get below error in

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement PARSEDATETIME(TIME_ORDER,'yyyy-MM-dd'T[*]'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ'))"; expected "[, ::, AT, FORMAT, *, /, %, +, -, ||, ~, !~, NOT, LIKE, ILIKE, REGEXP, IS, IN, BETWEEN, AND, OR, ,, )"; SQL statement:
```

tried multiple combination no clue , any suggestion or solution is much appreciated.
Thanks  in advance

Comment: Those datetime formats are designed in such a way that they are sortable chronologically purely by sorting them alphabetically. You don't have to parse it. Just treat it like any other string.

Comment: Do you know for certain that these strings *always* have padding zeros on the fractional second, so there are *always* nine digits after the decimal separator? This is a crucial factor in deciding on an optimal solution.

Answer (score 4):

In H2 you can cast strings with ISO timestamps to datetime data types directly, there is no need to mess with any functions:

```sql
SELECT TIME_ORDER FROM TABLE1
ORDER BY CAST(TIME_ORDER AS TIMESTAMP(9) WITH TIME ZONE);
```

Note: you need to specify exact fractional seconds precision of 9, because default is 6 that is not enough for your sample data and it is safer to use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, because plain `TIMESTAMP` can't distinguish timestamps during transitions from DST to normal time and other backward transitions, if your local time zone has them.

`PARSEDATETIME` supports only 3 fractional digits and has other issues. Compilation error in your case is caused by incorrect usage of `'`, these characters need to be specified twice inside SQL string literals, and also your pattern has incorrect raw `Z` at the end, you can fix these problems, but don't use it anyway, you can easily get incorrect ordering with this function due to its limitations.

You should also consider usage of `TIMESTAMP(9) WITH TIME ZONE` data type for `TIME_ORDER` column instead of character string data type.

Comment: Wow , worked as expected thanks @Evgenij . Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

## Alphabetical order is chronological order

If your data is guaranteed to *always*:

- Use padding spaces in the fractional second as needed to get nine digits after the decimal separator, *and*
- Use exactly that formatting (always FULL STOP rather than COMMA for decimal separator, contrary to the preference for comma recommended in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard)

…then you can simply sort your textual values as text. No need to do anything extra. Alphabetical order is also chronological order in this situation.

## Sorting

If those two bulleted rules are not always the case, then you must use either:

- the internal (H2) approach shown in the [Answer by Evgenij Ryazanov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67929923/642706), or
- the external (Java) approach shown in the [Answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67924352/642706).

## Use the type, Luke

The most robust solution is to store date-time values using date-time types. Storing date-time values as text is generally a poor table-design choice.

The SQL standard defines an array of date-time types. [H2 implements those types](http://h2database.com/html/datatypes.html). So use those types.

Your values end in a `Z`. This means the date-time is meant to be viewed through the lens of an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC. Commonly we call this simply "UTC time". The `Z` is pronounced “Zulu”, as in “Zulu time”, meaning “UTC time”. So the appropriate type in H2 for your inputs is [*TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE*](http://h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#timestamp_with_time_zone_type)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sorting them with SQL, you can retrieve them with JDBC and then sort them with Java code

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream.of(
                    "2021-03-08T01:00:01.000000800Z",
                    "2021-03-08T01:02:48.000000735Z",
                    "2021-03-08T12:58:02.000000016Z",
                    "2021-03-08T01:03:48.000000735Z",
                    "2021-03-08T01:04:48.000000735Z"
        )
        .map(s -> OffsetDateTime.parse(s))
        .sorted()
        .forEach(System.out::println);      
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-03-08T01:00:01.000000800Z
2021-03-08T01:02:48.000000735Z
2021-03-08T01:03:48.000000735Z
2021-03-08T01:04:48.000000735Z
2021-03-08T12:58:02.000000016Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/nV4s7D)

Comment: no , i need to sort them using the h2 as the data volume is huge

Comment: This method can generate real performance issues and should be avoid.

Comment: @PremKumarR If your data is guaranteed to be using padding zeros in the fractional second, you can simply sort as text within H2 database. If *not*, if the fractional second varies in number of digits, then the approach shown here or similar approach shown in [other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67929923/642706) becomes necessary as such values when sorted alphabetical are not chronological. I posted a comment asking to confirm the length of your actual data, but you’ve not responded.